# Proof involving intervals

Tags: real-analysis

If I := [a,b] and I' := [a',b'] are closed intervals in R, show that I is a subset of I' iff a'≤ a and b ≤ b'.  I think I have managed to prove one direction; Assume a'≤ a and b ≤ b'.  We want to show that I is a subset of I'.  Let x be an element of I.  Then a ≤ x ≤ b.  Since a' ≤ a, a' ≤ x.  Since b ≤ b', x ≤ b'.  Thus a' ≤ x ≤ b'.  Therefore x is an element of I' and I is a subset of I'.  Is this correct?  How do I show that if I is a subset of I' then
a'≤ a and b ≤ b'?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Have a look at the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first part is correct.

Suppose $I=[a,b]$, $I'=[a',b']$, and $I \subset I'$.  Then $a \in I$ so $a \in I'$ so $a' \leq a \leq b'$.  In particular, $a' \leq a$.  Similarly $b \in I$ leads to $b \leq b'$.